# Help with a particular Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I did the following problem but I am coming up with the wrong answer.

Problem:

Use Laplace transforms to solve the following system. All unknowns are
fuctions of $x$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
w'' + y + z &=& -1 \\
w + y'' - z &=& 0 \\
-w' - y' + z'' &=& 0 \\
w(0) = 0, w'(0) = 1 &\text{,}& y(0) = 0 \\
y'(0)= 0, z(0) = -1 &\text{,}& z'(0) = 1 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer:

\begin{eqnarray*}
s^2W(s) - 1 + Y(s) + Z(s) &=& -\frac{1}{s} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
    \text{ eq 1}\\
W(s) + s^2Y(s) - Z(s) &=& 0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
\text{ eq 2}\\
-sW(s) - sY(s) + s^2Z(s) + s + 1 &=& 0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
\text{ eq 3}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now I solve eq 2 for $W(s)$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
W(s) &=& -s^2Y(s) + Z(s) \\
s^2( -s^2Y(s) + Z(s) ) - 1 + Y(s) + Z(s) &=& -\frac{1}{s} \\
-s^4Y(s) + s^2Z(s) - 1 + Y(s) + Z(s) &=& -\frac{1}{s} \\
(s^2 + 1)Z(s) + (-s^4+1)Y(s) &=& 1 - \frac{1}{s} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
\text{ eq 4}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
-s( -s^2Y(s) + Z(s) )  - sY(s) + s^2Z(s) + s - 1 &=& 0 \\
s^3Y(s) - sZ(s)  - sY(s) + s^2Z(s) + s - 1 &=& 0 \\
(s^2 - s)Z(s) + s^3Y(s) - sY(s) + s - 1 &=& 0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
\text{eq 5}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now eq 4 and eq 5 represent a system of linear equations
with two unknowns. I now solve eq 4 for $Z(s)$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
(s^2 + 1)Z(s) + (-s^4+1)Y(s) &=& \frac{s-1}{s} \\
(s^2 + 1)Z(s) &=& (s^4-1)Y(s) + \frac{s-1}{s} \\
(s^3 + s)Z(s) &=& (s^5-s)Y(s) + s-1 \\
Z(s) &=& \frac{(s^5-s)Y(s) + s-1}{s^3+s} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now I subsitue into eq 5.
\begin{eqnarray*}
(s^2 - s)(\frac{(s^5-s)Y(s) + s-1}{s^3+s}) + s^3Y(s) - sY(s) + s - 1 &=& 0 \\
(s-1)(\frac{(s^5-s)Y(s) + s -1)}{s^2+1})+(s^2-s)Y(s) + s - 1 &=& 0 \\
(s-1)((s^5-s)Y(s) + s -1)+(s^2+1)(s^2-s)Y(s) + s(s^2+1) + s^2-1 &=& 0 \\
(s-1)((s^5-s)Y(s) + s -1)+(s^4-s^3+s^2-s)Y(s) + s^3+s + s^2-1 &=& 0 \\
(s-1)(s^5-s)Y(s) + s^2-s -s + 1 +(s^4-s^3+s^2-s)Y(s) + s^3+s + s^2-1 &=& 0 \\
(s-1)(s^5-s)Y(s) + (s^4-s^3+s^2-s)Y(s) + s^3+ 2s^2-s &=& 0 \\
(s^6-s^5-s^2+s)Y(s) + (s^4-s^3+s^2-s)Y(s) + s^3+ 2s^2-s &=& 0 \\
(s^6-s^5+s^4)Y(s) + s^3+ 2s^2-s &=& 0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
Y(s) &=& \frac{ -s^3- 2s^2+s} { (s^6-s^5+s^4) }
    = \frac{ -s^2- 2s+1} { (s^5-s^4+s^3) } \\
\end{eqnarray*}
The book's answer is:
\begin{eqnarray*}
y(x) &=& \cos x + 1 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore I conclude I am wrong. I am hoping somebody can point out where I
went wrong.
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Eqs.1-3. Do you agree with this ? :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You posted three changes to my equations. I do agree with two of changes. Here is what I now think:
\begin{eqnarray*}
s^2W(s) - s + Y(s) + Z(s) &=& -\frac{1}{s} \,\,\,\, eq1 \\
W(s) + s^2Y(s) - Z(s) &=& 0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\, eq2 \\
-sW(s) - sY(s) + s^2Z(s) + s - 1 &=& 0 \,\,\,\,\, eq3
\end{eqnarray*}
It is not $ -s - 1$ because $z(0) = -1$. Do you agree with these three equations?

Bob

Comment: No, it is not $+s$, it is $-s$ because $z'(0)=1$

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well, I used +s and I got the right solution and therefore I am not going to worry about it. I may have made an offsetting error. Not sure.         Bob